# Ubuntu 14.04LTS – Failing to connect second monitor - Requested size exceeds 3D hardware limit

Tags: 14.04, graphics, intel-graphics, bios

I know there are quite a few posts out there ... but still I can't figure it out. My setup:

```
ubunt 14.04 LTS

Memory: 3.9 GiB
Processor: Intel® Xeon(R) CPU E3110 @ 3.00GHz × 2 
Graphics: Intel® G33 x86/MMX/SSE2
OS type: 32-bit
Disk: 310.7 GB
```

In All Settings->Displays

I can see and activate both screens with resultion 1920x1080 (16:9) … but when trying to apply it I get this Error:

The selected configuration for displays could not be applied
Requested size (3840, 1093) exceeds 3D hardware limit (2048, 2048).
You must either rearrange the displays so that they fit within a (2048, 2048) square.

Failed to apply configuration: %s
GDBus.Error:org.gtk.GDBus.UnmappedGError.Quark._gnome_2drr_2derror_2dquark.Code3: Requested size (3840, 1093) exceeds 3D hardware limit (2048, 2048).
You must either rearrange the displays so that they fit within a (2048, 2048) square

When looking at display I see:

```
sudo lshw -C display

*-display:0             
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: 82G33/G31 Express Integrated Graphics Controller
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 10
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
   resources: irq:42 memory:fe980000-fe9fffff ioport:cc00(size=8) memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:fe800000-fe8fffff
*-display:1 UNCLAIMED
   description: Display controller
   product: 82G33/G31 Express Integrated Graphics Controller
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2.1
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.1
   version: 10
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:fe780000-fe7fffff
```

Comment: sounds to me like the graphics card cant handle that resolution it can only handle 2048, 2048 and 3840 is out of that range .. you may have to grab yourself a discrete graphics card.. im just going by the information given .. dont know if there is a way to fix the limitation of the hardware

Comment: What would I need to look for in this new graphics card (min requirement)? And discrete?!

Comment: use a lower resolution. so that the total is less than 2048. placing the monitors up and down instead of left and right will allow a higher resolution.

Comment: sorry discrete is just a name for a additional card where as yours is probably embedded ..part of the system as for what you would need, thats hard to say..I think pretty much all modern ones will handle it but you are looking at probably $100 or more. They do have cheaper ones but you will have to find one,then look for specs or ask like on Amazon if it can handle two 1080p monitors if its one of the 'cheaper' cards  some cheaper ones can handle it

Comment: also I guess nvidia may be easier to work with .. i hear AMD cards are sometimes troublesome in Linux/Ubuntu  tho i use one without issue but only a single monitor

Comment: Thanks for the additional information. I use a desktop computer in this case. Would adding a second card also work (for adding the missing performance)?

Comment: There's nothing especially painful about AMD cards in Linux, at least no more so than NVidia or Intel. BTW, your CPUs should support two monitors easily, assuming your motherboard has enough DisplayPort/HDMI sockets, or if it supports DisplayPort 1.2 so you can daisy-chain monitors.

Comment: How much memory do you have configured in BIOS to be assigned to the Intel graphics?

Comment: The embedded graphics card on the motherboard has a vga and dvi socket. The two monitors with resolution 1920x1080 (16:9) have each a hdmi and vga socket and cables for it. I also have a DVI to HDMI adapter. I tried to connect monitor 1 with the vga cable ... and monitor 2 with DVI to HDMI adapter ...

Comment: What do you mean by daisy-chain? And how and where can I look for how much memory is configured in BIOS to the Intel graphics? Should I restart and go into BIOS?

Comment: @dobey ... I checked the memory allocated. See my edit above ... . Would it help to change DVMT/FIXED Memory to Maximum DVMT and can I do so without any concern?

Comment: Daisy-chain is a feature of DisplayPort 1.2 or higher. It looks like you don't have that, so don't worry about it. Yes, the amount of assigned memory for video sounds too low, so I would try increasing it as much as possible first, before buying a discrete graphics card.

Comment: @dobey ... I changed DVMT/FIXED Memory to 'Maximum DVMT' in the BIOS ... but I still get the same error message: 'The selected configuration for displays could not be applied Requested size (3840, 1093) exceeds 3D hardware limit (2048, 2048)'  when I want to apply the display setting. When I run 'lspci -v -s 00:02.0' I also still see 'Memory at d0000000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]'. What else could I try?

Comment: Can you try to lower the resolution on both screens to 1024x768 (or less) to see if it will correctly support both displays?

Comment: It works with resolution on both screens to 1024x768! Yet the icons are so big :(